# Qml: Delegate/Model component for floating model items

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a dynamic set of QML components (these are based on/combine different controls like images, labels, ...) which are displayed on "arbitrary" positions within a parent control. The position of each component is defined by an underlying object (C++). At the moment I create and remove these components using [dynamic object creation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html), everytime a new underlying object is created or removed.

Although this works it would be much cleaner to use a delegate/model scheme with an underlying [QAbstractItemModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html). Is there a built in component for this, e.g. a component which allows free positioning of the QAbstractItemModel's items?

[EDIT]: Here is a depiction of what I mean:

[image]

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`Repeater`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-repeater.html#details), which is typically used with a row or a column to lay things out, but it will also work for standalone items.

In addition to that you also have signals for added and removed items.

```
  Repeater {
    model: 20
    delegate: Rectangle {
      width: 50
      height: 50
      color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 1)
      MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onPositionChanged: {
          parent.x += mouseX
          parent.y += mouseY
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly I was looking for.